# Filling out sysinfo struct in kernel mode?

Tags: c, linux-kernel

In user space, sys/sysinfo.h provides the int sysinfo(struct sysinfo *info) function. However, that is not the case in kernel space.

The linux/kernel.h header defines an int do_sysinfo(struct sysinfo *info) but when I compile with it the following happens:

1. It compiles with the warning that do_sysinfo is undefined.
2. This results in an undefined symbol error once insmod is run.

Any help is immensely appreciated.

Comment: Symbol `do_sysinfo` isn't exported (with `EXPORT_SYMBOL`), so it cannot be used by kernel modules. But what exact information you need from this function? It is unlikely that you module needs **all settings**.

Comment: What is the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: I'm trying to get system level statistics to a proc file. I did end up solving it but was wondering if there is another way.

Comment: Hi ! I would like to use "do_sysinfo()" in a syscall that I'm adding to a kernel. But I've got the exact same errors as you do. Did you find any solutions ? Thx in advance.

Comment: The "solution" I ended up with is to copy do_sysinfo() over.